# Send email through cron job

Tags: xml, python-3.x, cron, odoo-12

I am creating a custom module that will auto checkout employees who forgot to checkout at the end of the day and will send an email for the same.

I have created a function for auto checkout and email, Created a cron job and email template. I have configured mail servers as well and they are working fine.
Here is my code

```py
class hr_attendace(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['hr.attendance']


    def check_for_incomplete_attendances(self):

        not_checkout = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('check_out', '=', False)])
        for rec in not_checkout:

            date_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 18:29:59')
            rec.check_out = date_time

            email_template = self.env.ref('custom_attendance_2.email_template')
            if email_template:
                email_template.send_mail(rec.employee_id.work_email, force_send=True)
```

```xml
<odoo>
    <data noupdate = "1">
        <record id="ir_cron_module_auto_checkout" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Auto Checkout</field>
            <field eval="True" name="auto_checkout"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <!-- <field name="nextcall">2019-09-03</field> -->
            <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 18:29:59')"/>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field eval="True" name="doall" />
            <field name="model_id" ref="hr_attendance.model_hr_attendance"/>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                model.check_for_incomplete_attendances()
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="email_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Attendance Reminder Email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="hr_attendance.model_hr_attendance"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="False"/>
            <field name="email_from">shringarg@trinesis.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">${object.work_email}</field>
            <field name="subject">Attendance Reminder ${object.name}</field>
            <field name="body_html">
            <![CDATA[
            Hello ${object.name},<br/>
                    This is reminder that you didn't sign out today.<br/>
                    Best regards...<br/>]]>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I am getting these errors while running cron job. Employees are getting checked out but Mail is not getting sent.

2019-09-11 11:52:05,515 16973 WARNING auto_checkout odoo.models: mail.mail.create() with unknown fields: ., @, a, c, g, h, i, l, m, n, o, p, r, s, t, u 
2019-09-11 11:52:06,766 16973 INFO auto_checkout odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_mail: Sent batch 1 emails via mail server ID #False

Comment: I'm seeing the warning about unknown fields, where it lists every character in the destination email address.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nevermind, got it.  The `send_email` method takes a dictionary, and when you pass in a string it's iterating over the string, thinking it's a dictionary, and being unable to match any single one of the characters (since that's what you get when you iterate a string) to the key names in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any documentation to support this, but based on my own experimentation, the issue is passing a string to `send_mail`, which you do on this line:

```py
email_template.send_mail(rec.employee_id.work_email, force_send=True)
```

The `send_mail` method takes a dictionary as its first argument, where each key matches a field name your email template.  So for example, if you have this field:

```xml
<field name="email_to">${object.work_email}</field>
```

then you should make this call:

```py
email_template.send_mail({'email_to': rec.employee_id}, force_send=True)
```

The message `unknown fields: ., @, a, c, g, h, i, l, m, n, o, p, r, s, t, u` is indicative that you passed in a string; those are all of the characters present in the email address, (which I'm going to guess is your name at gmail dot com) which Odoo was trying to iterate over like it was a dictionary.